# Dynamically removing options from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to dynamically remove options from a select box..

```
<select name="goal1">
   <option value="1">Fat Loss</option>
   <option value="2">Competition Prep</option>
   <option value="3">Marathon Training</option>
   <option value="4">Lean Mass</option>
   <option value="5">Triathlon Training</option>
   <option value="6">HIIT Training</option>
   <option value="7">LISS Training</option>
</select>

<select name="goal2">
       <option value="1">Fat Loss</option>
       <option value="2">Competition Prep</option>
       <option value="3">Marathon Training</option>
       <option value="4">Lean Mass</option>
       <option value="5">Triathlon Training</option>
       <option value="6">HIIT Training</option>
       <option value="7">LISS Training</option>
    </select>

<select name="goal3">
       <option value="1">Fat Loss</option>
       <option value="2">Competition Prep</option>
       <option value="3">Marathon Training</option>
       <option value="4">Lean Mass</option>
       <option value="5">Triathlon Training</option>
       <option value="6">HIIT Training</option>
       <option value="7">LISS Training</option>
    </select>
```

There are, as you can see, three of these select boxes on the page with the exact same options, is there any way to dynamically remove options of the other select boxes based on selections made from the others.

So for example, if in the first of three select boxes, I choose 'Fat Loss', is there any way to remove that option from the other 2 select boxes to avoid duplication in the input?

Then if an option gets unselected, the option needs to reappear in the other select boxes..

Comment: What if you unselect an option that was selected previously from any of the other dropdowns? Do you want to get them back? else you could just do `var $mySelect = $('.mySelect');
$mySelect.on('change', function(){
  $mySelect.not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').remove();
})` http://jsbin.com/riyom/1/

Comment: Then it needs to reappear as an option in the others I guess.

Comment: Are the options same in all of them always?

Comment: Yep, the exact same options for all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, that works great, just if they get unselected..

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/awpwW/1/). When selecting an item in one of the three dropdown boxes, the options are removed from the other two.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select").on("change", function () {
        // Show all options
        $("option").show();

        // Get an array of all current selections
        var selected = [];
        $("select").each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        });

        // Remove all selected options, except the current showing one, from all lists
        $("select").each(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
                if (selected[i] != $(this).val()) {
                    $(this).find("option[value='" + selected[i] + "']").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: I've updated the fiddle with a new version which lets options reappear when they get unselected in other lists. Not sure if it's the best way of doing this though...

Comment: Doesn't quite work, if one gets unselected, it needs to reappear in the other option lists.

Comment: @BuzzLightyear I've updated the answer reflecting your extra needs.